# Using Type Predicates on a type that contains a Union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

Sorry for the weird title, super hard to word that

I have a few types defined:

```
type Selected = {
    ID: number
}

type DetailsV1 = {
    Status: number
}
type DetailsV2 = {
    Status: number,
    Date: string
}
type DetailsDTO =
    | DetailsV1
    | DetailsV2

type SelectedDetails = DetailsDTO & Selected
```

I also have a user defined type guard:

```
function detailsDTOIsV2(
        details: DetailsDTO
    ): details is DetailsV2{
        return (
            (details as DetailsV2)
                .Date !== undefined
        )
    }
```

When I have an object typed as `SelectedDetails` how can I access the `.Date` property?
Without some sort of type checking I get the `Property Date does not exist on type SelectedDetails`. But I don't see how to check the types when `SelectedDetails` is an intersection type, so is there another way to go about this?

Comment: So you want to access `SelectedDetails.Date` without type guard, right?

Comment: @wonderflame i want to access `SelectedDetails.Date` whatever way is possible.  I'm concerned that it's simply not possible to do this with intersection types.

Comment: well you can pass a variable typed as `SelectedDetails` to `detailsDTOIsV2` and it will have that property

Comment: interesting, that seems to work. I'm really surprised I can pass a `SelectedDetails` object to the `detailsDTOIsV2` function, since the function param is typed as `DetailsDTO`.  How does that even work?

Comment: Typeguard expects `DetailsDTO `, and `SelectedDetails` consists of `DetailsDTO` so there is no problem with it.  Does that work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer

Comment: Yup, this works perfectly for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a type-guard for the `DetailsV2` named `detailsDTOIsV2`, you can actually pass a `SelectedDetails` to it, since your type-guard expects a `DetailsDTO` and `SelectedDetails` is a sub-type of it. The reason why such assignment is allowed is due to Typescript's type system, which is known as [structural type system](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), that only checks if the assigned value matches the assigned type and doesn't fire an error if there are some extra fields that are not specified by the type.

Simply just pass the `selectedDetails` to the type-guard:

```
if(detailsDTOIsV2(selectedDetails)){
    selectedDetails.Date //works
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `in` operator that would achieve the same result:

```
if('Date' in selectedDetails) {
  selectedDetails.Date // works
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to narrow to the type that has that property. In this case you do that with the `in` operator.

```
selectedDetails.Date // type error

if ('Date' in selectedDetails) {
  selectedDetails.Date // fine
}
```

Here `'prop' in object` returns `true` if that property is exists on that object. And TypeScript will notice this and narrow your union to just the ones that have property.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhA2EDGwIBMoF4oG8BQUhUAkgCIBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE54C+eeokUpEwAQwCW8AM4A1AIxZcBIjEHAaoyrUYt2XcND6CREgEwz8RWIuWr6TZgBo5hUgNSVRwZkKoBzTdx39hYqQAKgDyWPZQAD68-vpSEdG6AYacvrAIyKhoSfoyOYGhUABk6Ygo6Jx4aMjwAszQSAD2VK5Qohnl2bFilHBlWfmile396IMAdI6oUAD0M1BpLMyNrHhCAGZQABQA5FMQO1AebR0D3aIAlLKEI5lj55NO0HNQ6x4Q7EA)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way around this.

The TS Compiler cannot infer whether SelectedDetails will have Date field or no without type guard